# paralell testing c# NUnit tests over Selenium grid

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, automated-tests

I have been investigating paralell testing c# NUnit tests over selnium grid, and am struggling to find any recent information on how to do this.

Does anyone know whether it can be done in v2.6.3 of NUnit?
Are there code examples available?
Are there alternatives to NUnit I should consider?

My investigation so far have revealed posts going back two years or more.  Some suggest its possible to do parallel testing in NUnit 2.5 or above but dont give explanations of how to achive this.

I have also come across MBUnit and PUnit, as suggestions, but again info is 2 or more years old and not very well explained.

Any help on this matter would be greadtly appreciated.

Comment: The sad truth is NUnit doesn't support parallelisation and will not until NUnit 3 is released. Your alternatives are the two you've listed but they are abandonware at best. Ultimately, C# doesn't have a reasonable, stable and uptodate parallel test runner.

Comment: @ Nguyen Vu Hoang - I dont have a snippet to provide - sorry.

Comment: @ Arran - thanks, ive had a go at PNunit but havent had much success.  i cant seem to find a potential relase date for Nunit 3, are you aware of when its likley to drop?